# rails turbolinks load javascript on single page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have a rails application using turbolinks

one page i should load script, and i don't want load it on all the application

specific add it on page like that

```
 <% content_for :head do %>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<% end %>
```

my problem is while i enter to page via turbolinks the script doesn't load

how can i load single js on specific page

thanks!

Comment: On the contrary to user3631047's answer, you should try to add `data-turbolinks-track="true"` in your `script` tag. I was in the similar situation, and doing so fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Turbolinks will NOT update `head`. That's where the advantage is. The loading speed will be much faster without head reloading. That's why your `content_for :head` won't work.

For your case, the simplest solution is to put the script tag directly on page template.

Comment: But what happen if I enter multiple times to the same page? each time the script will be loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe adding `data-no-turbolink` to your `script` tag helps you.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false" data-no-turbolink></script>
```